# What is the difference between a "Spring transaction" and a "Hibernate transaction"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Could you please explain the difference between the following two types of transactions:

1. Hibernate transaction
2. Spring transaction

Also I would like to know about the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: A Spring transaction manager (when configured properly) can manage hibernate transactions. `@Transactional` is the way to declare transactional methods in `Spring`. So the difference is the same as in a car wheel and a steering wheel, when "configured properly" rotating the steering wheel moves the car wheels ... and both are wheels :).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, for starters, they are both Transactions, but they encompass different concepts and components.

**TL;DR**

Hibernate deals with database specific transactions, whereas spring provides a general transaction management service. `@Transactional` is a nice way of configuring transaction management behaviour.

The long story:

**Transactions**

Transactions are basically units of work (i.e. changes to something) that are managed as a single operation that can be either committed or rolled back. There are lots of different types of transactions in the Java world - database, messaging systems like JMS, inter-application transactions (for those who are not faint of heart), or anything else that may need to be included in a transaction. In the Java standard, transactions are managed using the [Java Transaction API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) which sets the rules for how to participate in a transaction.

**Hibernate**

[Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/) is an ORM for abstracting database components to Java objects, so its transactions are specifically related to changes made within a database. A transaction may be made up of one or many writes to various database tables that are all committed once the operation is completed. Rolling back the transaction, e.g. if there are any errors during the operation, allows all the changes to be undone.

**Spring**

At its lowest level, [Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework) is an application framework for managing configuration and dependencies between objects. In addition, it also provides an interface for managing higher-level services that are used in modern applications, such as databases, messaging services, MVC frameworks, and transactions.

Spring is designed to be used as an all-encompassing master of objects and services within your application, so its concept of a transaction is at a higher level than the database specific transactions that hibernate concerns itself with. [Spring Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction.html) are designed to give you fine grained control of all your transactional resources while abstracting away the often messy coding required to co-ordinate the transactions.

**`@Transactional`**

Spring provides a few different methods for using transactions - among others, there are xml-based aspects, coding to the API, and annotation-based declarative transactions. The annotation-based transactions are handy because you don't need to add the transaction management boilerplate code to your app (even using PlatformTransactionManager via the API has quite a bit of coding overhead).

So basically, what happens with `@Transactional` is that, at runtime, spring scans your code base for @Transactional classes and methods and wraps them up in the transaction specific management code, based on what you have configured via the annotation. So a method like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public void saveAndSendMessage(Foo foo) throws Exception {
    dbManager.save(foo);
    Bar bar = transform(foo);
    jmsSystem.send(bar);
}
```

can have spring set up a new transaction for the database and jms system, and co-ordinate them without needing to add all the specific tx management code automagically.

Answer (score 2):

**Coding level deference**

**Spring**

In Spring, we can perform the transaction as below

```
@Transactional(readOnly=”false”)
public int insert(int studentId, String name, int courseId) {
    int outcome = 0;
    outcome = studentDao.insert(studentId, name);
    if (outcome > 0) {
   // re-intialize
        outcome = 0;
        outcome = studentCourseDao.insert(studentId, courseId);
    }
   return outcome;
}
```

After seeing the @Transactional, the Spring IOC container is going to perform the transaction. If both the operation successfully, then commit operation will be performed. If any operation failed then rollback operation will be performed.

**Hibernate**

In Hibernate we can perform the transaction as below

```
    public int insert(Student student, Course course) {
      //it is a flag driven transaction
    boolean flag = false;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Session session = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactoryRepo = null;
    try {
        sessionFactoryRepo = SessionFactoryRepo.getsessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactoryRepo.openSession();
        // here we are creating the transaction object
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        int outcome = 0;
        outcome =session.save(student);
        if (outcome > 0) {
          // re-intialize
            outcome = 0;
            outcome = session.save(course);
        }
        flag = true;
        return outcome;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally {
        if (flag == true) {
            transaction.commit();
        } else
            transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```